# How can I stop my American Standard Champion toilet from ghost flushing?

Tags: toilet, american-standard

90% certain it's a leaky "flapper" - I left the water turned off for a couple of days while we were out of town and the water level leaked right down to the seal of the flapper.

[image: This valve is a total piece of garbage and I hate it with my whole soul]

Here's the problem. It's brand new. I just bought & replaced the thing. But that didn't fix it. So I bought brand new seals. And that still didn't fix it. But I don't have fluid leaking out of anywhere else, just this flapper.

Aside from constantly turning the water off (or sealing the thing with concrete, which I really feel like doing after several months of fighting this thing), is there a way that I can get this thing to stop ghost flushing?

Comment: add dye or kool-aid to the tank to help track leakage

Comment: Is the tank well-sealed to the base? There could be leakage under the flapper valve-to-tank seal or between the bottom of the tank (usually held  by two brass bolts and three gaskets, one for each bolt and one for the porcelain-to-porcelain surfaces) and the top of the base unit.

Comment: @dandavis oh yeah, forgot to mention I did that trying to see if the leak was visible in the water currents... it wasn't, but the bowl turned green so the leak is definitely making it to the bowl.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I wondered about that, too, but there's no sign of leaks on the tank mounting bolts, and besides, the water never drained lower than the blue flapper valve seal.

Comment: Maybe you have a very tiny crack in the flush assembly you posted. Have you tried replacing that?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch yeah, the replacement, and the second set of replacement seals exhibit the same behavior